# When will we get Ryzen support?

Tags: release-loki

I am told that you do not support the ryzen cpu at this time.  Is that something I will see soon?

Comment: Hey, this is really a feature request - and the short answer is: No - because the LTS kernel doesn't support officially.  You can use Ukuu to upgrade kernel to 4.10 + and it should be fine. I use the Intel Kaby lake with an upgraded Kernel and added the firmware for it etc. Have a search around. Reddit has some Ubuntu forums for Ryzen that will help.

Comment: I have a ryzen and I did not have problems so far

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the kernel. I see that there are stability issues with Ryzen on Ubuntu 16.04, which elementary Loki is based. There are some work-arounds to get it stable.

What I would recommend is running elementary from a live USB for a bit to see how well it performs. If it does run ok you should be good.